# Get all tags of specific post in single record of mysql with XML PATH

Tags: mysql, sql, join, for-xml-path

I have news table like this

`````````````
news 
````````````
id          |   title     
------------+------------- 
1           |   test1
2           |   test2
`````````````

and

`````````````
tags
````````````
id          |   name     
------------+------------- 
1           |   tag1
2           |   tag2
`````````````

and

`````````````
news_tag
````````````
news_id     |   tag_id     
------------+------------- 
1           |   1
1           |   2
2           |   1
`````````````

Now I want to get this

```
newsid     |   title      |   tag_name 
------------+-------------------------- 
1           |   test1     |    tag1,tag2
2           |   test2     |   tag1
```

Comment: what did you try ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can show all the tag name on the same row using group_concat  and group by

```
  select n.newsid, n.title, group_concat(name) tag_name
  from news n 
  inner join new_tag nt on nt.news_id = n.id 
  inner join tags t on t.id = nt.tag_id 
  group by n.newsid, n.title
```